# How pause a loop in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, loops, settimeout, pause

Can anyone tell me why I'm not being able to pause the loop? The idea is to pause it for 5 seconds and then restart it. The code is bellow. Thanks!

```
let pics = [{
        name: 'picture',
        picture: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1491555103944-7c647fd857e6?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80',
        number: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'picture',
        picture: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1495837174058-628aafc7d610?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80',
        number: 2
    },
    {
        name: 'picture',
        picture: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1474314881477-04c4aac40a0e?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1050&q=80',
        number: 3
    }
];

let pauseLoop = false;

function displayImage() {
    let display = document.querySelector('#display');
    let button = document.querySelectorAll('.pic');

    for (let i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
        button[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
            display.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + pics[i].picture + "')";

            // THIS IS SUPPOSED TO PAUSE THE LOOP FOR 5 SECONDS AND THEN RESTART THE LOOP
            pauseLoop = true;

            setTimeout(function() {
                pauseLoop = false;
                console.log(pauseLoop)
            }, 5000);
        })
    }
}


// create list inside nav
let createGalleryMeny = () => {
    let nav = document.querySelector('#nav');

    for (let i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) {
        let img = document.createElement('DIV');
        img.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + pics[i].picture + "')";
        img.className = 'pic';
        nav.appendChild(img)
    }
}

// loop through every picture
function loopPics() {
    let number = 0;
    let display = document.querySelector('#display');

    display.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + pics[pics.length - 1].picture + "')";

    if (pauseLoop !== true) {
        setInterval(function() {
            display.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + pics[number].picture + "')";
            number++

            if (number === pics.length) {
                number = 0
            }
        }, 2000)
    }
}


(() => {
    createGalleryMeny();
    loopPics();
    displayImage()
})();
```

This code is just a simple gallery and I wanna have the option to pause the loop when one clicks any picture in the gallery, display the clicked picture and restart the loop after 5 seconds.

Comment: *Can anyone tell me why I'm not being able to pause the loop?* Because loops can't be paused? `setTimeout()` is an asynchronous operation and works at the same time as the loop does. The callback function only runs when a) the amount of time specified has elapsed and b) the JavaScript runtime is idle, meaning that the current function (and its loop) have finished.

Comment: @ScottMarcus see my post, it is possible, but it is probably not the best solution

Comment: @Niels Well, it's possible to write code that creates a delay, but technically, you can't pause a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Pause is not something you should want in Javascript, this blocks your whole code. You should create a function that will execute the code you want to repeat after X seconds. It can be a function which can call itself. If you do want to "wait" for a few seconds on a line of code it is possible.

Make the function async:

```
async function displayImage() {
```

And then wait for 5 seconds:

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
```

But your code is binding a click in the for loop, and you want to reexecute that code part. Which will result in multiple click handlers on 1 button depending on the timing. Which will probably not result in what you want.